# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at geotiff.js:3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the [geotiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geotiff) library in **angular 6.1.0** and **typescript 2.9.2**.

I installed it using

```
npm i geotiff
```

But I'm getting the following error in the browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>       at geotiff.js:3

After searching for this error, I came across many answers. I tried changing my `tsconfig.json` file.

Changed `module` to `es5`, `es6`, `none`. Didn't work.

Changed `target` to `es5`, `es6`. Didn't work.

Turned on `allowJs`. Didn't work.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the error You've mentioned, but there's definitely a problem with some imports inside the library itself.
After including this config in my package.json

```
 "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false
  }
```

import it like so

```
import GeoTiff, { fromUrl, fromUrls, fromArrayBuffer, fromBlob } from 'geotiff';
```

in app-component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    fromUrls("someUrl")
  }
}
```